# How to parse an XML file, grabbing data from specific elements

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, parsing, xml-parsing

so I have an XML file with data from a lot of instances of an object.  I'm parsing this file, but only want the data with the element tag "Content"

I am using `NSXMLParser`, so I have the methods `parserDidStartDocument`, `didStartElement`, `foundCharacters`, and `didEndElement`

So here is my current implementation

In Header:

```
@property (strong) NSMutableArray* AssetJSONObjects;
```

In Implementation:

boo

```
l grabContent = NO;

- (void) parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
    NSLog(@"parserDidStartDocument");
    self.AssetJSONObjects = [NSMutableArray new];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    NSLog(@"didStartElement --> %@", elementName);
    if([elementName isEqual:@"Content"])
    {
        grabContent = YES;
    }
}

-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
    NSLog(@"foundCharacters --> %@", string);
    if(grabContent)
    {
        [self.AssetJSONObjects addObject:string];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    NSLog(@"didEndElement   --> %@", elementName);
    if(grabContent)
    {
        grabContent = NO;
    }
}

- (void) parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
    NSLog(@"parserDidEndDocument");
}
```

So here is my question: is the way that I'm declaring/initializing my array, `AssetJSONObjects` legitimate?  Is the way I'm initializing my bool `grabContent` legitimate?  Is there a better way to grab data from specific tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went the cheap route, just kept track of a global boolean and set it if the tag was found

relevant code:

```
BOOL grabContent = NO;

- (void) parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
    self.AssetJSONObjects = [NSMutableArray new];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    if([elementName isEqual:@"Content"])
    {
        grabContent = YES;
    }
}

-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
    if(grabContent)
    {
        NSDictionary *JSONObject =
        [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                        options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                          error: nil];
       if (JSONObject)
       {
          [self.AssetJSONObjects addObject:JSONObject];
       }
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
    if(grabContent)
    {
        grabContent = NO;
    }
}

- (void) parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
    self.notifications = [self convertRawJSONToNotifications:self.AssetJSONObjects];
    if(self.notifications != nil)
    {
        self.notificationCompletionHandler(self.notifications, self.numNewNotifications);
    }
}
```